# How to get the input value written by interpolation code using Reactive Forms?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, visual-studio-code

In this case i'm using Reactive Forms not ngModel

I'm writting an interpolation value into an input text field

When i submit my form i get all the  field values, except the interpolated one.
The interpolated is empty

How to fix it??

```
<label class="form-control-sm"
         id="identificationCode"
         name="identificationCode">{{reference.value + "-" + publishDate.value}}
</label>
<input  #txtIdCode
         type="text" 
         id="idCode" 
         name="idCode"
         formControlName="txtIdCode"
         maxlength="15"                     
         value="{{reference.value + '-' + publishDate.value}}">
```

When i get txtIdCode in this way, i get an empty value but the input text is filled:

```
item.identificationCode = this.myForm.controls["txtIdCode"].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `value` attribute doesn't affect the `FormControl`. It will remain empty until the input field is changed.

In your case, binding the template reference variable with `ViewChild` will work.

component.ts

```ts
  @ViewChild('txtIdCode')
  txtIdCode: ElementRef
  ...

  submit() {
    item.identificationCode = txtIdCode.nativeElement.value
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute binding

```
[value]="reference.value + '-' + publishDate.value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `value` with form control, you need to set the actual value to the formcontrol itself:

Sample:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  txtIdCode: [this.reference.value + "-" + this.publishDate.value]
});
```

If you do not know the value when you create the form, use `patchValue()` when you do:

```
this.myForm.get('txtIdCode')
  .patchValue(this.reference.value + "-" + this.publishDate.value)
```